# Disable auto-population of Destination Database for Database Restore

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2016

Is there a way to disable the auto-population of the Destination Database when restoring from a Database Backup.  I would like to restore a production data backup of Database A to a TEST server and to a different instance (Database B) without accidentally wiping out the Database A instance on the TEST server.

Comment: Never restore databases via SSMS GUI. Write a RESTORE query and put there whatever Database for restoration you want.

Comment: The restore command does what you tell it to do. It does not "auto-populate" anything. So you need to use the correct options to avoid overwriting any existing database. As Slava indicates, that will likely be safer to do by writing the actual restore command by hand - especially if you do this on a recurring basis. The SSMS gui can certainly be confusing in this area, especially if you do not use it frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option to avoid a mishap like the one you mentioned would be to do the restores via T-SQL instead of the Restore wizard in SSMS.  If you're not familiar with the `RESTORE` command syntax you can view the documentation on this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).  You can also try generating a script from the GUI with all the options that you typically use, and executing this script with the file names substituted if they change.  To do this configure the Restore wizard with all of the options you normally use and look for `Script` button on the top of the `General` page.  On this button, press the arrow drop-down and you'll be able to generate a script directly to a file, query editor, or your clipboard.